# Heathrow public wi-fi and Data Retention Regulations

Tags: internet, european-union

My friend visited Heathrow airport and he used their public wifi. He said that he had to provide only his name and email and got access to the Internet. He had not validated his email to get access, I mean, there wasn't an email verification process.

But as far as I understand, there are some laws in Europe about public wifi. And that law says (I'm not sure, I found only Data Retention Regulations of 2009 related to this) that the provider of free wifi has some kind of responsibility for any illegal actions via wifi.

So I guess the provider of public wifi has to somehow map a wifi user to a real-world person for the case if a person has done some illegal. But it looks like the name and un-verified email is only data airport takes from the person

From:
[Heathrow Terms and Conditions & Privacy Notice for Wi-Fi Services](https://www.heathrow.com/file_source/Heathrow/Static/PDF/More/heathrow-Wi-Fi-privacy-notice.pdf).

How does it actually work? Am I right that they still have to be able to connect their wifi user with a real person?